# Schrodinger's equation for a free particle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers, physics

How do I find the most general solution to the Schrodinger's equation for a free particle: $$\dfrac{\partial \Psi(x, t)}{\partial t} = \dfrac{i\hbar}{2m} \dfrac{\partial^2 \Psi(x, t)}{\partial x^2}$$

with $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |\Psi(x, t)|^2 dx = 1\; \forall\; t$ ?

Is $$\Psi(x,t) = A e^{i\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}x} e^{−iEt/\hbar}$$ the most general solution?

Comment: This can be easily found in many text books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you wrote down is not the most general solution.  Since Schrödinger's equation is linear, any superposition of these solutions is a solution as well;  and so a much more general solution will be of the form
$$
\Psi(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty A(k) e^{i k x} e^{-i \hbar k^2 t/2m} \, dk.
$$
Effectively, this can be viewed as a "sum" of solutions with different $k$ values (with $E = \hbar^2 k^2/2m$), all with different amplitudes and phases $A(k)$.  The normalization constraint $\int |\Psi(x,t)|^2dx = 1$ translates into a constraint of the form $\int |A(k)|^2 dk$ is equal to some constant (I think it's $2\pi$, but I can't remember my Fourier transform normalizations just now.)

Also, note that your own solution $\Psi(x,t) = A e^{i\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}x} e^{−iEt/\hbar}$ cannot satisfy the normalization constraint. Since you have $|\Psi(x,t)|^2 = |A|^2$ everywhere, the normalization integral is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi(x,t)|^2 \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |A|^2 \, dx,
$$
which is divergent unless $A = 0$, in which case it vanishes.  There is no value of $A$ for which this integral is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Write the solution as $\Psi(x,t) = \phi(x)e^{-iEt/\hbar}$ and replace it into Schrodinger's equation

$$
-\frac{iE}{\hbar} \phi(x)e^{-iEt/\hbar} = \frac{i\hbar}{2m} e^{iEt/\hbar}\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x)}{\partial x^2}
$$

Rearranging,

$$
\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{2m E}{\hbar^2}\phi(x) = 0
$$

The more general solution to this equation is

$$
\phi(x) = Ae^{ik x}
$$

with

$$
k^2 = \frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}
$$

The normalization constant $A$ can be found from your constraint $\int{\rm d}x~|\phi(x)|^2 = 1$

Comment: But is $\Psi(x, t) = Ae^{i{\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}}x}e^{\frac{-iEt}{\hbar}}$ the most general solution?